# How to choose some elements by the same class?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, xpath-2.0

I need to select some elements by the same class.

*html pseudo-code:*

```
<div class="a">
    <div class="2">
    ...
    ...
    ...
        <div class="3">
            <div class="4">
            <div class="4">
<div class="b">
    <div class="2">
    ...
    ...
    ...
        <div class="3">
            <div class="4">
            <div class="4">
```

*python code:*

```
list = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[@class='a']/div[@class=...]/div[@class='2']/div[@class='3']")
```

I want to choose elements with `class="4"` from the branch beginning with `class="b"`. With my code I get list with null length. I tried variants with finding by css-selector but got the same result. There are no errors or exceptions.

Comment: Hint: All browsers have now an XPath expression evaluator available that makes testing XPath expressions easier than threough a Python app.

Comment: Please add the "xpath" tag to this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following `xpath`.

```
//div[@class='b']//div[@class='4']
```

---

```
list = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[@class='b']//div[@class='4']")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`descendant`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/XPath/Axes/descendant) XPath axe in order to select only the children of the div having [class attribute](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_class.asp) of `b`

Something like:

```
//div[@class='b']/descendant::*/div[@class='4']
```

should do the trick for you:

[image]

More information:

- [XPath Axes](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xpath_axes.asp)
- [XPath Operators & Functions](https://docs.experitest.com/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=40044727)

Comment: You probably haven't correctly restored the tag tree.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your time.

Answer (score 0):

Specifically, your situation is solved like this xPath:

```
//*[@class = "b"]//*[@class = "4"]
```

Or pointing to the `div` element:

```
//div[@class = "b"]//div[@class = "4"]
```

[image]